# Add property to database with the controller

Tags: php, html, symfony

my application have two entity `user` and `status`, every user can add zero or many status, actually I use the `entity` user in the status form, so when a user want to add status he can add a status for another user by the choice field.
I want that every status take automatically the id user?
I remove this part from status form :

`>add('patient','entity',array('class'=>'DoctorBundle:Patient','property'=>'id','multiple'=>false))`

and I change the status controller:

```
$id= $entity->setMedecin();
        $form = $this->createForm(new statutType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('statut_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Ajouter'));

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: the user can't add status for another user (no choice field ), but the id user take the value null in the data  base, every status have to take the id user, how can i make it ?